# Start listening to a port when someone visits a page? Node.js, Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, body-parser

I'm stuck between node.js, express, and a hard place trying to figure out how to listen on a port when someone views a webpage. My code works fine, as long as I can type node index.js in terminal to listen on port 3000....

In 3 days of searching for an answer- I have no direction. Not surprising with how fast my head is spinning.

**In short, how do I start listening on a port when someone views a webpage?**

What I'm trying to do [as securely as possible]:

- Take information from a submit form at submit.html
- Push form fields through express and Body-Parser
- Store it in a MySQL table on a remote server.

I have my code working as I want (minus a few access problems). It pulls the info when form submitted, parses it, picks up a MySQL connection in the pool (I think) and stores the data in the DB on the other server. As stated, this only works when I type node index.js in terminal first.

For the life of me, I cannot find anything about listening unless you type node index.js into terminal! **How do people start listening on a port when a visitor comes to your page (my case, a submit form)?**

I have a few ideas and need some direction. I feel like I'm missing one link to the chain, this is holding up my whole project.

**I THINK I need one of the following:**

- A tcplistener
- Use sockets.. like Socket.io
- http(s).createServer
- nginx port configuration to listen

**Am I on the right track? Are any of these what I need?** I've tried these and so many others but I can't figure out what I need when my code breaks every time I try implementing someones code.

Below is my code for laughing purposes.

This is the form that gets picked up by index.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Title</title>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<meta name="robots" content="dofollow" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="dofollow" />

<meta name="description" content=" " />

<meta name="google" content="nositelinkssearchbox" />

</meta>
</body>

<body>

<form id="data-form"  action="http://x.x.x.x:3000/form" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="uid" value="13">

URL:<br>
<input type="text" name="urll" value="Add"><br>

Title:<br>
<input type="text" name="title" value="Title"><br>

Description:<br>
<input type="text" name="blurb" value="Summary"><br>

Tags:<br>
<input type="text" name="tags" value="Three"><br>

<br>
Choose a thumbnail<br>
<br>

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
var mysql = require('mysql');

// Configure MySQL connection
var pool = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit: 50,
        host: 'x.x.x.x',
        user: 'xx',
        password: 'xxxx',
        database: 'rawdata'
  });

//Establish MySQL connection
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
   if (err)
      throw err;
   else {
       console.log('Connected to MySQL');
       // Start the app when connection is ready
       app.listen(3000);
       console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
 }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));

//allow express to access our file
app.get('/form/form.html', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/form/" + "form.html");
    });

//This sends the user information to the path
app.post('/form', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, connection){

    var jsondata = req.body;
    var values = [];

      values.push([jsondata.uid,jsondata.title,jsondata.tags]);

    //Bulk insert using nested array [ [a,b],[c,d] ] will be flattened to (a,b),(c,d)
    pool.query('INSERT INTO raw (uid, title, tags) VALUES ?', [values], function(err,result) {

      if(err) {
         console.log('Error' + err + req.body);
      }
     else {
         res.status(200).send('Done');
      }

    });
    });
```

Comment: You could buy a server from AWS, Digital Ocean, Google or any of the folks and then like you said you would run `node index.js` in one of them and log out of the server. That is how you would serve people worldwide.

Comment: `how do I start listening on a port when someone views a webpage`, the more I read your question, the less sense it makes to me. First, you have to listen on a port, then someone can connect to this port and reach your website. It sounds to me that you first want someone to connect (to "something" in the ether) in order to start listening on a port... in order... to... what? Other people to be able to connect to your app? I really don't understand what you're trying to do. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I had thought to do this but didn't think it was the proper way. If this what people use nodemon for? I use Digital Ocean, would I execute node index.js in the "Console" found on digitalocean.com?

Comment: @JeremyThille If I don't start my index.js file in terminal and leave terminal running and listening, I get "This site can’t be reached
x.x.x.x refused to connect." errors on any page the viewer views.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **serve-sent-events(sse)**,its a simple streaming technique.use `sse-nodejs` library to achieve this.you can add add a listener when you visit a page.
`server.js`

```
var SSE = require('sse-nodejs');

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req,res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname+ '/index.html');
});

app.get('/time', function (req,res) {
    var app = SSE(res);

    app.sendEvent('time', function () {
        return new Date
    },1000);

    app.disconnect(function () {
        console.log("disconnected");
    });

    app.removeEvent('time',3100);

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Simple SSE server start at port: 3000')
});
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
HELLO WORLD
<div id="clock"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var ev = new EventSource('/time');
    ev.addEventListener('time', function (result) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML += '<h4>' + result.data + '</h4>'
    })
</script> 
</html>
```